breaker compatibility ITE with GE Load Center
Is an I-T-E QP  breaker compatible with a Gen Elect Load Center? I have an older (1981) GE Load Center and it has an I-T-E QP breaker in it. I am told that this is not compatible.

GE panels need THQL breakers.
In some cases they accept THQP breakers - the panel labeling will say if they do. There will also be funny crossbars welded to every bus stab where a THQP fits.
Rarely, you see a GE panel that accepts THQL but won't fit a THQP.  These can take THQL or an obscure Eaton type called Type CL.
Not to be confused with CH or BR which you cannot use.

TL;DR No
ITE breakers/panels are now Siemens. Siemens still makes QP breakers. But a QP breaker (ITE or Siemens) is not officially compatible with GE panels. And a GE breaker is not officially compatible with an ITE or Siemens panel.
Your choices are a genuine GE breaker - e.g., THQL1120 - or an Eaton CL breaker - e.g., CL120.
Breakers and panels are an interesting situation. On the one hand, all panels that take 1" breakers are largely the same and all panels that take 3/4" breakers are largely the same as well. On the other hand, there are some differences. For a mix of proprietary reasons (a company might make a lot more money selling all the breakers in a panel than selling the panel itself) and safety reasons (if things don't fit exactly right then arcing - and fires - can happen), and because there is no standard for how everything fits together, you have to use breakers that match the panel. Generally speaking, that means the original manufacturer or its successor (so ITE/Siemens, Cutler Hammer/Eaton, etc.).
However, Eaton, in addition to making breakers for their two main panel lines (CH, originally Cutler Hammer; BR, originally Bryant) also makes CL breakers which can be used for Square D Homeline, GE Type THQ, Crouse-Hinds Type MP, Thomas and Betts Type TB, Murray Type MP, ITE/Siemens Type QP) and CHQ breakers which can be used for Square D QO breakers.
So would the reverse work - i.e., mix and match within the "CL" compatible group? Sort of. But not necessarily reliably. And that means when it comes to safety (possibly) and insurance claims (definitely!) if there is ever a fire you have a potentially BIG problem. Simply not worth the risk when a typical standard trip (not AFCI or GFCI) single breaker is under $10 and a double-breaker under $20.

Although this is all good info, it's probably more info than you really need to know for your situation.   The label inside the load center should specify all allowed breaker types, so just check the label to see what's allowed in your specific load center, and if there are non-allowed breakers swap them out as soon as possible with approved ones.

just check the label to see what's allowed in your specific load center - Except that the label isn't going to list Eaton CL. It is important to know that in some panels there are some alternatives that are 100% legitimate.
